# Intellij missing syntax highlighting for Java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I'm really desperate to find a solution for this. For some weird reason, IDEA is not showing a complete syntax highlighting for my Java code. I already tried changing the "sources root", checking power mod, deleting the .ignore plugin, but i still getting this odd look on my code. 
I've imported it as a maven project through the pom.xml file.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you are using some custom editor color scheme. Does it help if you [switch it back to Darcula](https://i.imgur.com/h10FuJA.png)?

Comment: No, it doesn't. In fact, i was using Darcula and getting the same error. I tried switching through different color schemes, but nothing changed in the highlighting beyond the colors.

Comment: All the features work in the editor, only the colors are not default. Darcula looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/iP1D79R.png). You may have some third-party plug-in installed which overrides IDE themes/colors.

Comment: Well, i've found a solution. By reseting the Java inspections checkbox, it turned on the syntax highlighting back for all themes but this. Anyway, now i can go back to work. Thanks so much for the hint!

Comment: About Darkula, sorry for not specifying : the theme in the print is not Darkula, is some downloaded "DK Monokai".  I used darkula once, them tried to change the themes hopping that it would solve the syntax problem.  The Inspections checkbox was the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in the comments above, the problem was related to the "DK Monokai" theme (must have been downloaded somewhere, i can't remember) and somehow, resetting the Settings -> Editor -> Inspections checkbox for Java worked for all themes but this one. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you have changed the IntelliJ appearance or the shortcuts?

For appearance check the configuration, File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance

For shortcuts, File -> Settings -> Keymaps

For editor settings, File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java

Please, let me know if this works for you

Comment: Hey there. As i said in the comments above, the problem was related to the "DK Monokai" theme (must have been downloaded somewhere, i can't remember) and somehow, reseting the Settings -> Editor -> Inspections checkbox for Java worked for all themes but this one. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think it was a theme related issue, I was doing a clean install with the default dark theme and I had the same issue, and I also fixed it thanks to the inspections checkbox for Java and Scala.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling power saving mode in Intellij IDEA did the trick.